# Create a call using WebClient that depends on the response body from another WebClient call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I was dipping my toes with the new Spring Reactive Framework (As we're planning on migrating our APIs to Spring Boot 3). I was looking on to how to get the response from an earlier WebClient call before initiating the second WebClient call. When I tried to use `.block()` to wait for the response from the first call, I get an exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio`.

I have some Node.js experience so I have been using `Promises` and `await` in a Node.js context.

Here's an example of what I wanted to achieve using a Node.js code block:

```
const firstDownstreamResponse = await axios.post(url, body);
const elementFromFirstDownstreamCall = firstDownstreamResponse.data;
const secondDownstreamResponse = await axios.post(url2, elementFromFirstDownstreamCall);
```

I tried using the WebClient as such:

```
Foo2 downstreamResponse1 = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(url).build()
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .body(Mono.just(body), Foo.class)
        .retrieve().bodyToMono(Foo2.class).block(); // I get an error here

Foo3 downstreamResponse2 = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(url2).build()
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .body(Mono.just(downstreamResponse1), Foo2.class)
        .retrieve().bodyToMono(Foo3.class).block();
```

Additional question/s: How would I approach WebClient if I wanted to do some further orchestration to the response data before I returning it to the controller, in the cases wherein the API response structure is different from the downstream response that I get from the WebClient?

```
Foo2 downstreamResponse = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(url).build()
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .body(Mono.just(body), Foo.class)
        .retrieve().bodyToMono(Foo2.class).bloick()

FooApiResponse fooApiResp = modifyResponse(downstreamResponse); // this will change the downstream response to one that conforms to the API spec.
```

Also, how can I ensure that there will be contents to the response body getting sent back to the consumer when they initiate a call to the Reactive API microservice? As I might be wondering if there will be a case where some consuming applications might get a blank response body whilst the Reactive API are still waiting for the downstream responses.

(In the case of Node.js we can use `await` for both these purposes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 "my" main rules in the reactor concept:

1. Never block thread
2. Never leave out the context, that is, do not implement big business logic in like a "map"
3. If you use a blocking library, always wrap it! https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking

> Suggestion: I think it's easier with Kotlin Coroutine the WebFlux, so
> we do our own and company projects in Kotlin. At least, that's what we
> do. Coroutine is compatible with WebFlux and vice-versa and does not
> need a stream-like structure, but the main rules are still live.

What you want do:

```java
return WebClient
    .builder()
    // ...
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(Foo2.class)
    .flatMap(foo2 -> {
         return WebClient
            .builder()
            // ...
            .body(Mono.just(foo3), Foo2.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Foo3.class);
     });
```

Comment: `Avoid making CPU-intensive implementations` never heard of this "rule" just make sure you use parallel fluxes and split it out on cpu cores if you are to do CPU-intensive work.

Comment: You are right. I was unclear.